# Find the start and ending sector index of a file in Windows 7

Tags: python-2.7, windows-7, operating-system, disk, sector

Hi I would like to find the actual physical starting and ending index of a file on Windows 7. Is there an operating system command that can help me finding this. A python script or C program would also solve the purpose. Any kind of related help or suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think Operating Systems typically let you access the actual locations of memory.  They run most applications using virtual memory to prevent hacking.

Comment: See [FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364572%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).